# NativeScript File.readSync() not working if there is space in file name

Tags: ios, nativescript-angular

I am making an app for ios using nativescript angular. I am selecting and converting a file to base64 to send to server easily. Everything works correctly but if a file has space in it eg: 'myFile 1' then the path of that file is read as 'myFile%201' and I think this is the reason that readSync() is not working. Here is my Code.

```
const files = await openFilePicker({
            multipleSelection:true,
            // extensions:['application/pdf','application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','png','jpeg']
            // extensions:['application/pdf','application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']
            // extensions:[]
            
        })

        for(let result of files['files'])
        {
            // extra line to see console easily/
            console.log("");
            console.log("result is : ",result)
            let selectedFile:File;
            
            if(isAndroid)
            {
                selectedFile = File.fromPath(result);
                
            }
            else
            {
                selectedFile = File.fromPath(result.replace("file://",""));
            }

            console.log("");
            console.log("\n\nselected File : ", selectedFile)

            if(this.isExtensionAllowed(selectedFile['_extension']))
            {
                if(this.maxAttachmentCount <= 0)
                {
                    this.maxAttachmentCount=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.maxAttachmentCount--;
                }

                let data = selectedFile.readSync();
    
                console.log("")
                console.log("data is : ",data)
                let base64File = "";
                if(isIOS)
                {
                    base64File = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    base64File =  android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data,android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
                }

                
                console.log("");
                console.log("base64 is  : ", base64File)
                let attachmentInfo = {name:selectedFile['_name'],extension:'.'+selectedFile['_extension'],
                                base64:base64File};

                if(this.base64Attachments.length == 4)
                {
                    this.base64Attachments.shift();
                }

                (<any[]>this.base64Attachments).push(attachmentInfo);
            }

        }
```

And here is a screenshot of file name without space which is working:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of file name with space which is not working:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to go to ChatGPT for answer. Apparently I had to use decodeURI(path) to get decoded path and then use File.fromPath.

```
               if(isAndroid)
                {
                    selectedFile = File.fromPath(result);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    result = decodeURI(result);
                    selectedFile = File.fromPath(result.replace("file://",""));
                }
```